# Finding the order of a subgroup of a finite abelian group as a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $p^m$. Suppose that $G$ is a direct sum of $t$ cyclic groups. Show that the subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $0$ and order $p$ elements has order $p^t$.

By the structure theorem of finite abelian groups, we have
\begin{equation}
G=\mathbb{Z}a_1 \oplus … \oplus \mathbb{Z}a_t
\end{equation}
where each $a_i$ has order $p^{\alpha_i}$ and $\alpha_1+…+\alpha_t=m$. Since direct summands are cyclic, each of their elements is an integral multiple of some fixed $a_i$ in $G$. So every $x\in G$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
x=\sum_{i=1}^tn_ia_i,
\end{equation}
and the order of $x$ is the least common multiple of the orders of elements $n_ia_i$.
At this moment, I don’t know how to find the order of $H$. What does an element of order $p$ looks like in terms of the $\mathbb{Z}a_i$ ?
Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: $0\le n_i<p^{\alpha_i},$ and $x$ is of order $1$ or $p$ iff for each $i, $$n_i$ is a multiple of $p^{\alpha_i-1}.$

Comment: Oh, of course ! Thank you ! So I must have $H=\mathbb{Z}b_1 \oplus…\oplus \mathbb{Z}b_t$ where $b_i= p^{\alpha_i - 1}a_i$. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.